# Interest Modeling Problem Mistake?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, finance, mathematical-modeling, initial-value-problems

> Adriana opens a savings account with an initial deposit of $\$1000$. The annual rate is $6\%$, compounded continuously. Adriana pledges that each year, her annual deposit (deposited continuously) will exceed that of the previous year by $\$500$. How much will be in the account at the end of the tenth year?

First I calculated the annual deposit $D$, via $D' = D + 500, D(0) = 1000$, to find that $D = 1500e^t - 500$.

Then I calculated $P(10)$, where $P$ is the balance at time $t$, via $P' = .06P + 1500e^t - 500, P(0) = 1000$.  However, this yields ~$\$35\ million$, which seems very high.  I checked the ODE solutions on Wolfram, so my mistake must be in the modeling.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

$D = 1000+500t$

$P' = 0.06P+1000+500t$

Solving this would give

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%27(t)+%3D+0.06p%2B1000%2B500t

$p(t) = c_1e^{0.06t} - 8333.33t -155556$

$p(0) = c_1 - 155556 = 1000$

$c_1 = 156556$

Now
$p(t) = 156556e^{0.06t} - 8333.33t - 155556$

Now $p(10) = 46374$

Comment: I believe this approach would be for discrete compounding and depositing, not for continuous?

Comment: when you say deposited continuously, what do you mean by it. I have never come across this.  The approach what i have given is good for continuous compounding but for the so called discrete depositing.

Comment: I am doing Exercise 10 on page 127 at https://www.academia.edu/32329978/_John_Polking_Differential_Equations_with_Boundary  Note that recurrence relations aren't introduced until just after Exercise 10, which has led me to believe that Exercises 1-10 implicitly assume deposits/withdrawals/payments are somehow made continuously (i.e., the deposit/withdrawal/payment is non zero between any times $t$ and $\Delta t$).

Comment: Also, I am confused about how your solution represent continuous compounding.  If the time between $n$ and $n + 1$ is a year, isn't that annual compounding?

Comment: Can you check if this is the answer?

Comment: Ahhh yes, I managed to find a full solution manual (https://www.scribd.com/doc/133899961/Instructor-Solutions-Manual-differential-Equations-With-Boundary-Value-Problems-2e-polking book page 88, PDF page 97) and it seems your edited answer is correct.  My only question is, why do we solve $S' = .01S$ to find the salary in Exercise 9 (linked in above comment, solution linked in this comment), but $D' = D + 500$ to find the deposit in Exercise 10 doesn't work?

Comment: Answer to my previous comment:  "annual deposit will exceed that of the previous year by \$500" translates to $D' = 500$, not $D' = D + 500$.

Comment: I think the problem is missing information. We have an "initial" deposit which is deposited instantaneously in a lump sum at the beginning--this is correctly modeled as $P(0)=1000$ here and in the answer key. Then we have an "annual" deposit "deposited continuously" that increases by $500$ each year. But what is it in the first year? And does "deposited continuously" imply "increases continuously"? I don't think so. And if it does increase continuously, is the "annual deposit" for the first year one year times the rate at the start of the year, at the end of the year, or halfway through?

Comment: Frankly I think Adriana would satisfy the conditions of the problem if she deposited $0.01$ (one cent) per day throughout the first year, $1.38$ per day ($500$ more per year) throughout the second year, and so forth. How that would qualify as "continuous" I don't know, but the whole "continuous deposit" notion is absurd to begin with.